# How to combine a 2D texture in one color format with the swap chain in other color format?

Tags: directx-11

I have a swap chain whose usage is DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT. The swap chain's format is DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM.

Then I have a separate 2D texture in DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2 format. Is there a way to render that texture on the back buffer from the swap chain? Of course, assuming that VGA card can handle the YUV->RGB conversion.

If necessary, I'll provide more information!

Edit:
I'm planning to fill the YUV texture with the 8-bit YUY2 values (32-bits == 2 pixels). Should I use vertex shader, or pixel shader to convert that to floats? If yes, then I would ask for some info on how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swap chain can only be RGBA8 or RGBA16. You should be aware that the swap chain expect a srgb image (gamma 2.2) in RGBA8 and linear image if usige RGBA16.

This is the only two mode your swap chain can display. There is video overlay capabilities that could display a YUV surface directly, but i am not familiar with them, and it will not be a display from your swap chain. In your case, the simplest is to write a pixel or compute shader that take the YUV data and convert it to the swap chain final format.